# Rstudio crashes when using writeRaster()

Tags: memory, rstudio, raster

I am trying to write a raster stack to disk after processing the stack with the following code:

```
for (i in 1:nlayers(Tmin.Stack)) {
    tt <- Tmin.Stack[[i]][]
    tt[i < Wheat.P.r[]] <-  NA
    Tmin.Stack[[i]][] <- tt
}
```

Where `Tmin.Stack` is a stack of twelve rasters representing monthly temperature data (.bil files), and `Wheat.P.r` is a single raster of crop planting dates (.grd file). Each raster is large, consisting of a 1km global grid.

The `for` loop runs fine, but when I try to `writeRaster()` to disk, RStudio crashes. I tried to `writeRaster()` suspecting some memory issue, but Rstudio still crashes. Previously I have written other stacks/bricks of comparable size to disc, so why this issue now? Any thoughts on why this might be and how I might get around this issue?

Comment: Your post suggests you are using `writeRaster` on the entire stack. Have you tried adding `writeRaster(Tmin.Stack[[i]], ...)` to the loop?

Comment: @jbaums, I had tried using `writeRaster(Tmin.Stack[[i]],...)` outside of the `for` loop, but not inside. Following your suggestion, I moved it inside and got a new error message which says: Error in writeBin(v, x@file@con, size = x@file@dsize) : only 2^31-1 bytes can be written in a single writeBin() call. So it looks like it is a memory issue. The "Writing Raster Functions" Vignette suggests writing rasters row-by-row for large files, but I am not sure how I would do this for a raster stack.

Comment: Take a look at `?writeValues` - it has a couple of examples that might help.

Comment: You are not showing much of your code. But the use of `[]` is not a good idea in a script as it loads all values into RAM ans that is likely to lead to to memory issues with large files.